# Are begging and ball homonyms in spoken mandarin?

Tags: pronunciation, pinyin

Are 求 (beg) and 球 (ball) both written in pinyin as Qiú homonyms? I am trying to get the pronunciation for ball right. Are there authoritative homonym lists maintained somewhere?

Comment: Yes, they are. Any Chinese dictionary with Pinyin as index would be a good place to find homonym characters.

Comment: A fun fact: because they share the same pronunciation, chinese teenagers now type "ball ball 您" instead of "求求您" to express "i am begging you" when chatting online .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are both written in pinyin as 'Qiú'.
You can check [新華字典](https://zidian.911cha.com) for more details.
It is a trustable dictionary website.